# Change declaration and construction of an object in JAVA

Tags: java, proxy, refactoring, javassist, automated-refactoring

I have two questions which bear relation.

The first question is if there is some approach to declare the implementation of an interface in java during execution time in order to avoid the next error:

```
  IObject obj = new Object();
```

The Object Object doesn't implements the interface IObject.

The second question is that I want to change the declaration and construction of an object in java in order to create its proxy. Following you can see an example.

The source code which I want to change is:

```
  Object obj = new Object();
```

The target object which I want to reach is the next one:

```
  IObject objProxy = (IObject) ProxyFactory.generateProxy(new Object());
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You can change classes in a Java program. However, you would need to apply the changes during the build and prior to running your program. This limits you to classes that you define and excludes any JVM classes which are not part of your artifact.

One possible approach would be to use [Byte Buddy](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy) which offers a mechanism to write `Plugin`s that are triggered on build.

The above code shows how to implement `IObject` for any class named `pkg.Object`:

```
public class SimplePlugin implements Plugin {
  @Override
  public boolean matches(TypeDescription target) {
    return target.getName().equals("pkg.Object");
  }
  @Override
  public DynamicType.Builder<?> apply(
    DynamicType.Builder<?> builder,
    TypeDescription typeDescription
  ) {
    return builder.implement(IObject.class);
  }
}
```

You can activate the plugin to be run during your Maven build by the following:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
  <artifactId>byte-buddy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>transform</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <transformations>
      <transformation>
        <plugin>pkg.SimplePlugin</plugin>
      </transformation>
    </transformations>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

As for replacing the construction of the object, you would need to change the byte code of the class. You would need to detect any instruction that creates an instance of your class and replace it with a factory call. You can do so using ASM which is exposed by Byte Buddy via the `AsmVisitorWrapper`.